# How to get create/last modified dates of a file in Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, file

I want to get a files these attributes as integer values.

Comment: Why an integer, whats wrong with TDateTime?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Delphians tend to like the `FindFirst` approach (the `SearchRec` structure has some of those), but I'd suggest the Win32 API function `GetFileAttributesEx`.

Answer (score 15):

Try

```
function FileAge(const FileName: string; out FileDateTime: TDateTime): Boolean;
```

From SysUtils.

Comment: Deprecated as of time of this comment.

Comment: `FileAge()` gets the CREATE date of the file, not the LAST MODIFIED date.

Comment: @JerryGagnon - No, it uses `_WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA.ftLastWriteTime`

Comment: @HX_unbanned - only the first overload (returning a FileTime) is deprecated

Comment: That overload was added in Delphi 2006 (in case somebody else runs into a compile error with older versions)

Answer (score 9):

From the [DSiWin32](http://17slon.com/gp/gp/dsiwin32.htm) freeware library:

```
function DSiFileTimeToDateTime(fileTime: TFileTime; var dateTime: TDateTime): boolean;
var
  sysTime: TSystemTime;
begin
  Result := FileTimeToSystemTime(fileTime, sysTime);
  if Result then
    dateTime := SystemTimeToDateTime(sysTime);
end; { DSiFileTimeToDateTime }

function  DSiGetFileTimes(const fileName: string; var creationTime, lastAccessTime,
  lastModificationTime: TDateTime): boolean; 
var
  fileHandle            : cardinal;
  fsCreationTime        : TFileTime;
  fsLastAccessTime      : TFileTime;
  fsLastModificationTime: TFileTime;
begin
  Result := false;
  fileHandle := CreateFile(PChar(fileName), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil,
    OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
  if fileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then try
    Result :=
      GetFileTime(fileHandle, @fsCreationTime, @fsLastAccessTime,
         @fsLastModificationTime) and
      DSiFileTimeToDateTime(fsCreationTime, creationTime) and
      DSiFileTimeToDateTime(fsLastAccessTime, lastAccessTime) and
      DSiFileTimeToDateTime(fsLastModificationTime, lastModificationTime);
  finally
    CloseHandle(fileHandle);
  end;
end; { DSiGetFileTimes }
```

Comment: why var rather than out parameter - you don't seem to use the value that comes in?

Comment: Valid point. I'm an 'old school' programmer, I learned it before 'out' was invented and I automatically use 'var' in all occasions.

Answer (score 5):

```
function GetFileModDate(filename : string) : TDateTime;
var
   F : TSearchRec;
begin
   FindFirst(filename,faAnyFile,F);
   Result := F.TimeStamp;
   //if you really wanted an Int, change the return type and use this line:
   //Result := F.Time;
   FindClose(F);
end;
```

F.Time has since been Deprecated, Help file says Use F.TimeStamp.
Just to update this due to later versions of Delphi

Answer (score 5):

System.IOUtils do have a TFile record with several functions for getting file age, e.g. GetCreationTime, GetLastAccessTime, GetLastWriteTime

Answer (score 4):

This should work, and it is native Delphi code.

```
function GetFileModDate(filename : string) : integer;
var
  F : TSearchRec;
begin
  FindFirst(filename,faAnyFile,F);
  Result := F.Time;
  //if you wanted a TDateTime, change the return type and use this line:
  //Result := FileDateToDatetime(F.Time);
  FindClose(F);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call the [GetFileInformationByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364952.aspx) winapi function. Aparently [JCL](http://homepages.codegear.com/jedi/jcl/) has a GetFileLastWrite function you could also use