# what i can set create/last modified/last access of a file?

Tags: delphi, file, delphi-xe2

in:  [How to get create/last modified dates of a file in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144453/how-to-get-create-last-modified-dates-of-a-file-in-delphi) i have found as get create/last modified/last access date/time of a un file, but for set this value in a file, what i can to do?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [`SysUtils.FileSetDate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.FileSetDate) function from the SysUtils unit, which internally call the `SetFileTime` WinApi function.

this funcion has two versions

```
function FileSetDate(const FileName: string; Age: Integer): Integer;
function FileSetDate(Handle: THandle; Age: Integer): Integer;
```

The Age parameter is the Time to set. You must use the [`DateTimeToFileDate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.DateTimeToFileDate) to convert a [TDateTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TDateTime) Value to the Windows OS time stamp.

Like this

```
FileSetDate(FileName, DateTimeToFileDate(Now));
```

Comment: +1 This is liable to be more portable now that we can target non Windows platforms. But it only allows modification of the last modified date. Do you know if there is anything portable for the other time values?

Comment: Yeah the IOUtils (in the newer versions of delphi) unit has a full set of functions to set the datetime of files and directories.

Comment: @David, at least they have separate implementations for Windows and Posix.

Comment: @Uwe I actually think your answer is probably the best approach. That's why I deleted my own inferior answer.

Comment: How about `atime` and `ctime`?

Answer (score 15):

In unit `IOUtils.pas` you can find the corresponding methods in the records `TFile` and `TDirectory`: `SetCreationTime`, `SetLastAccesstime`, `SetLastWriteTime` accompanied by their UTC sibblings.