# How to get File Created, Accessed and Modified dates the same as windows properties?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I am trying to get the same Created, Accessed and Modified dates as appears in the windows properties as in:

[image: File Properties]

But am finding the times are consistently 30 minutes out:

[image: File Properties Delphi]

Believe it may have something to do with timezones/daylight savings but have been unable to find a solution.  Have tried looking at:
     TimeZone Bias and adjusting and looking at different methods including:
[How to get create/last modified dates of a file in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144453/how-to-get-create-last-modified-dates-of-a-file-in-delphi)

Current code:

```
var
MyFd TWin32FindData;
FName: string;
MyTime: TFileTime;
MySysTime: TSystemTime;
myDate, CreateTime, AccessTime, ModTime: TDateTime; 
Begin
 ...
 FindFirstFile(PChar(FName), MyFd);
 MyTime:=MyFd.ftCreationTime;
 FileTimeToSystemTime(MyTime, MySysTime);
 myDate := EncodeDateTime(MySysTime.wYear, MySysTime.wMonth, MySysTime.wDay, MySysTime.wHour,
 MySysTime.wMinute, MySysTime.wSecond, MySysTime.wMilliseconds);
 Memo1.Lines.Add('Created: '+ FormatDateTime('dddd, d mmmm yyyy, hh:mm:ss ampm', MyDate));
 ...
```

Any help appreciated

Thanks
Paul

Comment: You did not tell us how you are currently obtaining the information.

Comment: David - addded the current code but had tried numerous methods

Comment: OK, you are missing the conversion from UTC to local time. My answer and also Kobik's show how to do that.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your current code, but I believe this code will do what you need, using standard Windows API calls.

```
procedure TMyForm.ReportFileTimes(const FileName: string);

  procedure ReportTime(const Name: string; const FileTime: TFileTime);
  var
    SystemTime, LocalTime: TSystemTime;
  begin
    if not FileTimeToSystemTime(FileTime, SystemTime) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    if not SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(nil, SystemTime, LocalTime) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Name + ': ' + DateTimeToStr(SystemTimeToDateTime(LocalTime)));
  end;

var
  fad: TWin32FileAttributeData;

begin
  if not GetFileAttributesEx(PChar(FileName), GetFileExInfoStandard, @fad) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  Memo1.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(FileName);
  ReportTime('Created', fad.ftCreationTime);
  ReportTime('Modified', fad.ftLastWriteTime);
  ReportTime('Accessed', fad.ftLastAccessTime);
end;

procedure TMyForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ReportFileTimes(Edit1.Text);
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the code below to transform a UTC date time value to a local date time vale:

```
uses
  Windows;

function UTCTimeToLocalTime(const aValue: TDateTime): TDateTime;
var
  lBias: Integer;
  lTZI: TTimeZoneInformation;
begin
  lBias := 0;
  case GetTimeZoneInformation(lTZI) of
    TIME_ZONE_ID_UNKNOWN:
      lBias := lTZI.Bias;
    TIME_ZONE_ID_DAYLIGHT:
      lBias := lTZI.Bias + lTZI.DaylightBias;
    TIME_ZONE_ID_STANDARD:
      lBias := lTZI.Bias + lTZI.StandardBias;
  end;
  // UTC = local time + bias
  // bias is in number of minutes, TDateTime is in days
  Result := aValue - (lBias / (24 * 60));
end;
```

Judging from your images your offset is actually 10 hours and 30 minutes. Are you located in South Australia?

Comment: Henrick, Yes Adelaide South Australia.  This was able to convert all the times to the same as in the windows properties.  Appreciate your time

Comment: You've got him! :-) Another way is `FileTimeToLocalFileTime`